# (Question in a solution)If $M$ is finitely presented, $L$ is finitely generated

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Problem.) Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $0\rightarrow L\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow M\rightarrow0$ an exact sequence. Prove if $M$ is finitely presented, $L$ is finitely generated.

Solution from a book.) Assume $M$ is finitely presented; say $R^l\rightarrow R^m\rightarrow M\rightarrow0$ is a finite presentation. Let $L'$ be the image of $R^l$. Then $L'\bigoplus R^n\cong L\bigoplus R^m$ by Schauel's Lemma. Hence

> $L$ is a quotient of $R^l\bigoplus R^n$.

Thus $L$ is finitely generated.

> Question.) Shouldn't the line, '$L$ is a quotient of $R^l\bigoplus R^n$' be '$L$ is a quotient of $L'\bigoplus R^n$'? Then since $L'$ is
>   the image of a finitely generated module($R^l$), $L'$ is finitely
>   generated and $L$ is finitely generated as $L$ is a quotient of
>   finitely generated module($L'\bigoplus R^n$). I think $R^l$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $L'(\subset R^m)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L'$ is the image of $R^\ell$, it's a quotient of $R^\ell$ by the first isomorphism theorem. It follows that $L$ is a quotient of $R^\ell \oplus R^n$ by the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I see. $L'=R^l/ker$ and $L'\bigoplus R^n=(R^l/ker)\bigoplus R^n=(R^l\bigoplus R^n)/(ker\bigoplus0)$ and the isomorphic image of $0\bigoplus R^m$ in $L'\bigoplus R^n$ is of the form $A/(ker\bigoplus 0)$. So $L=(L\bigoplus R^m)/(0\bigoplus R^m)=((R^l\bigoplus R^n)/(ker\bigoplus0))/(A/(ker\bigoplus0))=(R^l\bigoplus R^n)/A$. Thank you very much!

Comment: No prob. Happy to help!